# CSS Clearing floats

Tags: css, css-float

I'm working two layers of floats, and the attempt to clear them does not seem to be working properly.

Here is the page:  http://cloud-catering.com/new/about.php

The Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/MLS1984/twrXh/

The fiddle doesn't show the issue properly though, so the site is a better reference for the issue.   I'm not sure why when I'm using the:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

to clear the previous floats, the photos under the lists are moved all the way to the right.

Comment: they're on the left for me, what browser are you having this issue in?

Comment: The should be flowing under the lists, not all the way to the left.  I'm using firefox

Comment: they're exactly where they should be according to your code. the only reason why the lists are shifted to the right is because of your menu to the left of them. once you clear after the lists there's nothing preventing the images from shifting all the way to the left now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try extending your left-hand menu all the way down the page. Or put a margin to the left of the images. See my comment above for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :after pseudoclass to clear floats, it's easier

```
.myDiv:after { content:''; display:block; clear:both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the clearfix trick.

Without using clear: both|left|right it will force a container to clear it's child elements, making it ideal to use in a situation where there might be right and left floated content and a middle container with floating elements....

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

It's a lot better than using extra tags to clear containers/floating elements if you just want to contain them in their parent page....